# What additional skills can a manual tester acquire to get back into the industry?

Tags: manual-testing

I have worked in manual testing for about 3 years and took a break for the past 2 years.I am now trying to get back in the game,but want to update myself, which will complement my testing skills and aid in getting a job.I am considering learning automation tool like selenium or getting into any of the ETL testing tools.Can you please share your thoughts on which would be better?Thanks a ton.

Comment: While I love that some answers were able to be given to this, I'm afraid this question is too difficult to answer objectively. I can certainly sympathize with your situation and I do hope you find the skills you need to be competitive in the job market, but you have to consider "Is there really a best answer for a question like this" and I'm afraid there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what skills you currently have, it's pretty hard to suggest new skills to acquire.

Basically, you should consider acquiring any skills that you don't have which are required in your local market.

Selenium might be appropriate. Agile testing might work. Mobile testing might make sense.

But also performance testing, website testing, etc, etc.

Check your local job sites to see what kind of skills are in demand for the kinds of jobs you want, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

For working as a manual tester probably you'll not be requested to know testing tools, it would be more useful having a general good experience with operating systems, databases and network tools. Those are the base for executing manual test that is not a simple point and click. So my suggestion is looking around to understand what techonologies the software houses of your target are looking for and go that way.